# How to add an element to a clone element before inserting it to another section of the document using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have the following html code

```
<tr class='mainrow'>
  <td class='firstName'>John</td>
  <td class='lastName'>Macfarland</td>
</tr>
```

Now I clone the above html code using jquery..

```
var mainrowCloned = $(".mainrow").clone(true);
```

After cloning the mainrow, I now need to add another column to the mainrowCloned element like in html code below but how to accomplish this in jquery code?

```
<tr class='mainrow'>
  <td class='newColumn'>Date</td>
  <td class='firstName'>John</td>
  <td class='lastName'>Macfarland</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use the [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table>
  <tr class='mainrow'>
    <td class='firstName'>John</td>
    <td class='lastName'>Macfarland</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>ndksaj</button>
<table class="tmp"></table>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.tmp').html('');
    $(".mainrow").clone().appendTo('.tmp');
    $('.tmp > tbody > tr.mainrow').append("<td class='newColumn'>Date</td>");
  });
</script>
```

now you can use innerHTML of div tmp

Comment: According to the solution, there is no way to add an element to a clone element before inserting it to another section of the document?

Comment: i don't think so.
but if you do not want to display it before modification you can make tmp hidden.